# JS/HTML | Submit onClick, when it's in POST form (js beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got on my **index.php** form with POST method.
Action is **form.php**, so it's different file, but I'm using iframe to show my result, still being at **index.php**.

One more thing that I need, is to show one of my text inputs, still on **index.php**, when I do click submit button. I've tried to use onClick action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showamount()
{
var price = document.getElementById('amount').value;
document.getElementById("some_p").innerHTML = price;
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="amount" />
<input type="submit" value="Podlicz"  onclick="showamount()"  />
<p id="some_p"></p>
```

It does not work there, when submit button is dedicated to form, with an action (I suppose, because it works without form, when is pure like above)

What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Submit buttons with forms submit the page...

Comment: @epascarello can't I do both?

Comment: Can you be physically in two places at once?

Comment: you could try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8bstkq7u/3/

Comment: @epascarello If I am understanding the question correctly, I think OP wants the form.php to open an iframe and update the current index.php with the same button click. might need AJAX but it should be possible.

Comment: This should be done via an AJAX Post, rather than a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<form id="form" onSubmit="return showamount();" action="form.php" target="_blank">`

That will open a new window to run the `form.php` and will also update current page with inputed value.

javascript

```
<script>
function showamount()
{
var price = document.getElementById('amount').value;
document.getElementById("some_p").innerHTML = price;
return true;
}
</script>
```

html

```
<form id="form" onSubmit="return showamount();" action="form.php" target="_blank">
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<input type="submit" value="Podlicz"  onclick="showamount()"  />
</form>
<p id="some_p"></p>
```